# nullreferenceexception in visual studio

Tags: c#, nullreferenceexception

I am getting a NullReferenceException in my code.

I call a method datecheck from another other page in the same project and pass two strings as parameters. These contain the date selected by user in string format.
Now when i try to initialize 2 labels label1 and label2 with these string values I get the NullReferenceException.

Code lines showing error and stack trace is as follows:

```
Line 39:         public void datecheck(String s1, String s2)
Line 40:         {
Line 41:             Label1.Text = s1;
Line 42:             Label2.Text = s2;            
Line 43:         }
```

Source File: I:\Aditya\GuestHouse\GuestHouseApp\GuestHouseApp\Booking Status.aspx.cs    Line: 41

Stack Trace:

> [NullReferenceException: Object
>   reference not set to an instance of an
>   object.]
>   GuestHouseApp.Booking_Status.datecheck(String
>   s1, String s2) in
>   I:\Aditya\GuestHouse\GuestHouseApp\GuestHouseApp\Booking
>   Status.aspx.cs:41
>   GuestHouseApp.Booking.Button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in
>   I:\Aditya\GuestHouse\GuestHouseApp\GuestHouseApp\Booking.aspx.cs:28
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs
>   e) +113
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String
>   eventArgument) +112
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String
>   eventArgument) +10
>   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler
>   sourceControl, String eventArgument) +13
>   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection
>   postData) +36
>   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean
>   includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +5348

Comment: You have not yet intialized `Label1` ... double check that. Simply assigning a value to the .Text property does not initialize the Label control

Comment: Almost all cases of `NullReferenceException` are the same. Please see "[What is a NullReferenceException in .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-in-net)" for some hints.

Answer (score 4):

Pay attention to the error message and line numbers. Here is how to read the stack trace:

**Object reference [is null and is] not set to an instance of an object [in method] GuestHouseApp.Booking_Status.datecheck [at file:line] Status.aspx.cs:41**

If the compiled code is up to date then this means that the line `Label1.Text = s1;` is the line that raises the exception.

Furthermore, it can be deduced that `Label1` is null because a NullReferenceException is raised when this happens: `(anExpressionEvaluatingToNull).Member`. The only member on an *explicit receiver* (which may be null) that is being accessed in that line is `Text` so then `Label1` must be null.

Use the debugger if needed: then you can inspect the current variables and objects.

Happy coding.

Comment: Your explanation is good, but what if the Text-property of Label1 had something like `if(value == null) throw new NullReferenceException();`? Wouldn't that mean that the problem might be s1 beeing null? Though you'd probably get an extra line in the stacktrace.

Comment: @Alxandr: a `string` can be null - it is *loosely* handled much like that of an empty string. The only time this would be an issue is you were to perform a function that requires `(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(s1))`

Comment: @IAbstract: Yeah, I know, but that was my point. If that's the case, it might not be Label1 that's null.

Comment: @Alxandr: A `.Text` property will not care. It isn't trying to parse anything by default - only for display. If the OP had something else happening when the `.Text` property changes, then the exception would not be at `Label1`; or, the operation could result in an initialization exception.

Comment: @Alxandr If the exception was raised from inside the `Text` property this would have been reflected as being another level on the stack-trace (it would have started from the `Text` property setter). That's how it's possible to tell it originated from that line -- and not from inside `Text`.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing Label1 has not been initialized.